# Standard Normal Table

Tags: statistics

I was wondering how do we get a standard distribution variable if we can't get it from the table. For example: I have
$$
-\frac{1}{3}
$$
How am I supposed to get the standard distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are wondering to have the probability of the desired quantile, that is

$$P\left(Z\leq -\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

Often Standard normal tables are tabulated only for the positive quantiles, but for the negative ones you can use the symmetry of gaussian distribution, thus

$$P\left(Z\leq -\frac{1}{3}\right)=1-P\left(Z\leq \frac{1}{3}\right)=0.3694$$

---

> I am actually wondering about how to get the value of P(Z≤1/3), sorry
> I miss-formulated my question.

If you use a standard paper table you have only an approx result: $\frac{1}{3}\approx0.33$ thus your probability is 0.6293

[image]

If you want the exact result of 0.630558659818236... you need a calculator

Comment: I am actually wondering about how to get the value of P(Z≤1/3), sorry I miss-formulated my question. Because in the standard table we only have 0.33 and 0.34 values not 0.33333...